# Block all tor traffic from my server

Tags: iptables, tor

I'm trying to prevent all traffic from Tor exit nodes from hitting my website. I've searched and have attempted a few of the solutions, this is what I've done.

I curled the https://check.torproject.org/cgi-bin/TorBulkExitList.py for my server IP into a text file (after removing the comment blocks), then loaded the IPs into iptables with DROP, yet I can still access my site via Tor connection. This list supposedly has all exit nodes on it, and updates periodically, however the exit node I was using didn't seem to be on my iptables list. When I manually added the IP I was coming from to fail2ban, it immediately blocked my tor connection to the website.

So it would seem that the TorBulkExitList.py doesn't actually contain all the exit nodes as you would expect, or something is going wrong. The IPs add to iptables with no problems, but it isn't actually dropping the connections.

Has anyone else here succeeded in blocking all Tor traffic, and if so, can you share your method? Thanks in advance for any information you may have about accomplishing this.

Comment: I haven't done this, but I found [another question](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74443/is-there-a-way-to-block-all-tor-traffic-incident-on-my-public-servers) which seems very similar.  Have you had a look there, yet?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. This is essentially what I've already done. The IPs are correctly showing as being set to DROP in iptables, however it either appears to not be blocking at all, or that the list provided by the torproject is incomplete. I changed my identity many times while testing tor and was able to make a connection to my website each time.